# Using dokuwiki plugin directly from php file

Tags: php, dokuwiki

I am new to php and I would really be grateful if you could help me! I have to add a word cloud to the sidebar of a page constructed using dokuwiki. The side panel is called using an independent php file (that is not managed by the doku). I believe that the way I can accomplish this is by calling the word cloud plugins functions directly in the side panel.php file. Can anyone give me the exact syntax for this or at least some way to start. Anything that I am doing now seems to be causing websites not to display at all. I have attached the code for the plugin that is located in syntax.php. Thanks!

```
<?php
/**
 * Cloud Plugin: shows a cloud of the most frequently used words
 *
 * @license    GPL 2 (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html)
 * @author     Esther Brunner <wikidesign@gmail.com>
 */
// must be run within Dokuwiki
if(!defined('DOKU_INC')) die();

if (!defined('DOKU_LF')) define('DOKU_LF', "\n");
if (!defined('DOKU_TAB')) define('DOKU_TAB', "\t");
if (!defined('DOKU_PLUGIN')) define('DOKU_PLUGIN',DOKU_INC.'lib/plugins/');

require_once(DOKU_PLUGIN.'syntax.php');

class syntax_plugin_cloud extends DokuWiki_Syntax_Plugin {

    function getType() { return 'substition'; }
    function getPType() { return 'block'; }
    function getSort() { return 98; }

    function connectTo($mode) {
        $this->Lexer->addSpecialPattern('~~\w*?CLOUD.*?~~', $mode, 'plugin_cloud');
    }

    function handle($match, $state, $pos, &$handler) {
        $match = substr($match, 2, -2); // strip markup

        if (substr($match, 0, 3) == 'TAG') {
            $type = 'tag';
        } elseif (substr($match, 0, 6) == 'SEARCH') {
            $type = 'search';
        } else {
            $type = 'word';
        }

        list($num, $ns) = explode('>', $match, 2);
        list($junk, $num) = explode(':', $num, 2);

        if (!is_numeric($num)) $num = 50;
        if(!is_null($ns)) $namespaces = explode('|', $ns);

        return array($type, $num, $namespaces);
    }            

    function render($mode, &$renderer, $data) {
        global $conf;

        list($type, $num, $namespaces) = $data;

        if ($mode == 'xhtml') {

            if ($type == 'tag') { // we need the tag helper plugin
                if (plugin_isdisabled('tag') || (!$tag = plugin_load('helper', 'tag'))) {
                    msg('The Tag Plugin must be installed to display tag clouds.', -1);
                    return false;
                }
                $cloud = $this->_getTagCloud($num, $min, $max, $namespaces, $tag);
            } elseif($type == 'search') {
                $helper = plugin_load('helper', 'searchstats');
                if($helper) {
                    $cloud = $helper->getSearchWordArray($num);
                    // calculate min/max values
                    $min = PHP_INT_MAX;
                    $max = 0;
                    foreach ($cloud as $size) {
                        $min = min($size, $min);
                        $max = max($size, $max);
                    }
                } else {
                    msg('You have to install the searchstats plugin to use this feature.', -1);
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                $cloud = $this->_getWordCloud($num, $min, $max);
            }
            if (!is_array($cloud) || empty($cloud)) return false;
            $delta = ($max-$min)/16;

            // prevent caching to ensure the included pages are always fresh
            $renderer->info['cache'] = false;

            // and render the cloud
            $renderer->doc .= '<div class="cloud">'.DOKU_LF;
            foreach ($cloud as $word => $size) {
                if ($size < $min+round($delta)) $class = 'cloud1';
                elseif ($size < $min+round(2*$delta)) $class = 'cloud2';
                elseif ($size < $min+round(4*$delta)) $class = 'cloud3';
                elseif ($size < $min+round(8*$delta)) $class = 'cloud4';
                else $class = 'cloud5';

                $name = $word;
                if ($type == 'tag') {
                    $id = $word;
                    $exists = false;
                    resolve_pageID($tag->namespace, $id, $exists);
                    if($exists) {
                        $link = wl($id);
                        if($conf['useheading']) {
                            $name = p_get_first_heading($id, false);
                        } else {
                            $name = $word;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $link = wl($id, array('do'=>'showtag', 'tag'=>$word));
                    }
                    $title = $word;
                    $class .= ($exists ? '_tag1' : '_tag2');
                } else {
                    if($conf['userewrite'] == 2) {
                        $link = wl($word, array('do'=>'search', 'id'=>$word));
                        $title = $size;
                    } else {
                        $link = wl($word, 'do=search');
                        $title = $size;
                    }
                }

                $renderer->doc .= DOKU_TAB . '<a href="' . $link . '" class="' . $class .'"'
                               .' title="' . $title . '">' . hsc($name) . '</a>' . DOKU_LF;
            }
            $renderer->doc .= '</div>' . DOKU_LF;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the sorted word cloud array
     */
    function _getWordCloud($num, &$min, &$max) {
        global $conf;

        // load stopwords
        $swfile   = DOKU_INC.'inc/lang/'.$conf['lang'].'/stopwords.txt';
        if (@file_exists($swfile)) $stopwords = file($swfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        else $stopwords = array();

        // load extra local stopwords
        $swfile = DOKU_CONF.'stopwords.txt';
        if (@file_exists($swfile)) $stopwords = array_merge($stopwords, file($swfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));

        $cloud = array();

        if (@file_exists($conf['indexdir'].'/page.idx')) { // new word-length based index
            require_once(DOKU_INC.'inc/indexer.php');

            $n = $this->getConf('minimum_word_length'); // minimum word length
            $lengths = idx_indexLengths($n);
            foreach ($lengths as $len) {
                $idx      = idx_getIndex('i', $len);
                $word_idx = idx_getIndex('w', $len);

                $this->_addWordsToCloud($cloud, $idx, $word_idx, $stopwords);
            }

        } else {                                          // old index
            $idx      = file($conf['cachedir'].'/index.idx');
            $word_idx = file($conf['cachedir'].'/word.idx');

            $this->_addWordsToCloud($cloud, $idx, $word_idx, $stopwords);
        }
        return $this->_sortCloud($cloud, $num, $min, $max);
    }

    /**
     * Adds all words in given index as $word => $freq to $cloud array
     */
    function _addWordsToCloud(&$cloud, $idx, $word_idx, &$stopwords) {
        $wcount = count($word_idx);

        // collect the frequency of the words
        for ($i = 0; $i < $wcount; $i++) {
            $key = trim($word_idx[$i]);
            if (!is_int(array_search($key, $stopwords))) {
                $value = explode(':', $idx[$i]);
                if (!trim($value[0])) continue;
                $cloud[$key] = count($value);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the sorted tag cloud array
     */
    function _getTagCloud($num, &$min, &$max, $namespaces = NULL, &$tag) {
        $cloud = $tag->tagOccurrences(NULL, $namespaces, true, $this->getConf('list_tags_of_subns'));

        $blacklist = $this->getConf('tag_blacklist');
        if(!empty($blacklist)) {
            $blacklist = explode(',', $blacklist);
            $blacklist = str_replace(' ', '', $blacklist);  // remove spaces

            foreach ($blacklist as $tag) {
                if (isset($cloud[$tag]))
                    unset($cloud[$tag]);
            }
        }

        return $this->_sortCloud($cloud, $num, $min, $max);
    }

    /**
     * Sorts and slices the cloud
     */
    function _sortCloud($cloud, $num, &$min, &$max) {
        if(empty($cloud)) return;

        // sort by frequency, then alphabetically
        arsort($cloud);
        $cloud = array_chunk($cloud, $num, true);
        $max = current($cloud[0]);
        $min = end($cloud[0]);
        ksort($cloud[0]);

        return $cloud[0];
    }
}
// vim:ts=4:sw=4:et:
```